# When to use type definition for basic types

Tags: go, type-definition

My question is about the type definition in Go and when to use it for basic types.
Consider the following example.
I have this struct which represents a row from my Database:

```
type DBEntityAttribute struct {
    Id              uint64
    EntityId        uint64
    EndPointNumber  uint8
    AttributeNumber uint8
    ParentId        uint64
    Value           string
    Tag             int
    ContentType     sql.NullString
    Maturity        int
    Author          int
    AttributeType   string
    IsNegated       bool
}
```

The EntityId and AttributeNumber are properties I use in A LOT of other structs everywhere in the code.
Now I wanted to refactor it to something like this:

```
type EntityId uint64

type AttributeNumber uint8

type DBEntityAttribute struct {
        Id              uint64
        EntityId        EntityId
        EndPointNumber  uint8
        AttributeNumber AttributeNumber
        ParentId        uint64
        Value           string
        Tag             int
        ContentType     sql.NullString
        Maturity        int
        Author          int
        AttributeType   string
        IsNegated       bool
    }
```

This would allow me to change the type of the EntityId and AttributeNumber at one single place. Also, when I pass for example an entityId as a function parameter, I can now give it the specific EntityId type, instead of the anonymous uint64.

My question is now:

- is this considered good Go code?
- where should I stop, meaning should I declare a distinct type for every property that is used elsewhere in the code? Or only for the important ones?

I know this is probably subjective, but often the Go community agrees on certain patterns and I want to comply with their guidelines.

Comment: These are broad questions: Yes, this is not unreasonable. If EntityId and Attribute Number might acquire methods it is very reasonable. Stop when it doesn't make sense. Strings are strings and ints are ints. Do not fall into the "but what if I want to change it someday?"-trap. First you won't make most changes and second: Changing in Go is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule about when to use a custom type.  My personal rule would be:

### Use a custom type when there's a reason.

Your reason, of wanting to change the underlying type in a single location seems like a good reason.

Other good reasons would be:

- To assign a custom JSON (un)marshaler, or other interface method
- As documentation
- In conjunction with constants, to act as an enum
- Improved type safety (avoid accidentally assigning a `FooID` to a `BarID`)

Comment: Especially your second point (as documentation) was what I had in mind, because I have a lot of types that have the same type (for example uint64) but mean totally different things. Sometimes, these properties are used as keys in maps, which makes it even more confusing, when you use them at different locations in the code

Comment: Also, to avoid confusion and mistakes, like if you have a function that would otherwise take 3 uint64 arguments, all of which are IDs.

Comment: yes exactly. Until now, my documentation was to give the parameters very descriptive names, like entityId uint64, databaseId uint64, etc... With type definitions, this becomes way clearer

Comment: It also provides additional type safety. You can't have `a MyIDType` and `b uint64` and then `c := a + b` without a type conversion. This can sometimes help prevent simple mistakes at compile time (though it doesn't prevent mistakes with untyped constant literals).

Comment: @Adrian: This is reaaaally a good point. It makes my decision on which types should get an own defined custom type way easier and clearer. Everytime I have properties that have the same type and are used frequently in the same locations and can easily be switched (e.g. a method requires params id1 uint64 and id2 uint64, but you accidentally call the method with (id2, id1)) a custom type is the solution here